# Detect when my UIView subclass is added to another UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I want my UIView subclass to position itself automatically when it is added to a parent container view.

Can I somehow detect when it is added and run my positioning code then or do I need to do something like?

```
[parentView addSubview:subView];
[setView calcPosition];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UIView** provides the methods `willMoveToSuperview:` and `didMoveToSuperview`. Just override those to know when the view is added to another view (or later removed).

Answer (score 0):

Write `calcPosition` methord inside the subview and call it from the `didMoveToSuperview` of subview

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    [self calcPosition];
}
```